# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, vector, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to build a model in Spark ML using Linear Regression in IntellijIDEA.

Before fitting the model, i am supposed to create a `VectorAssembler` having `feature` column.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

//creating features column
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("col4","col5","col6","col7"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler   at
>   energydata$.main(energydata.scala:35)     at
>   energydata.main(energydata.scala) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 2 more

But this gives error in Intellij. When i tried the same in spark-shell, it works.

can anybody suggest where I might be going wrong here??

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
```

Comment: Try to `Invalidate Caches and Restart` intellij

Comment: well, remove the "provided" keyword from the mllib dependency, apparently these classes are missing at runtime

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with other classes that it couldn't find. And it was because, in the maven dependency, it said "`<scope>provided</scope>`". I removed that, pressed reload, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face same error while running spark application. i have just remove (%%"provide")
scope of dependency spark sql